# matrices product and angle

Tags: matrices

proof for equality of angles (cosines) between 2 matrices

Comment: Hint: $(uA^T)(uA^T)^T=uA^TAu^T=uu^T$ etc. (I assume you're taking $u,\,v$ to be row vectors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visibly, as you apply the matrix $A^T$ on the right to $u$ and $v$, it means that $u$ and $v$ are **row** vectors.

Instead of row vectors $uA^T$ and $vA^T$, it is better to work with corresponding **column** vectors  $(uA^T)^T=Au^T$ and $(vA^T)^T=Av^T$.

First of all: dot product

$$(Au^T).(Av^T)=(Au^T)^T(Av^T)=uA^TAv^T=uv^T=u.v \tag{1}$$

Besides

$$\|Au^T\|^2=(Au^T)^TAu^T=uA^TAu^T=uu^T=\|u^T\|^2 \ \implies \ \|Au^T\|=\|u^T\|\tag{2}$$

Therefore

$$\cos(Au^T,Av^T)=\dfrac{1}{\|Au^T\|\|Av^T\|}(Au^T).(Av^T)=$$

$$=\dfrac{1}{\|u^T\|\|v^T\|}(u^T).(v^T)=\cos(u^T,v^T)$$